# V-matrix in SVD of A

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I have some doubts in understanding the concept of SVD.

1)
Let's assume I have a matrix
$$V^H=
\begin{bmatrix}
f &e&g&f\\ 
c &d&d&k\\
m &f&j&e\\
p &l&a&r\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I would like to find $V^{(o)H}$. Is it the last two columns or 2 last rows?

edit 1: I changed a matrix

Comment: That's not a matrix: the dimensions in the product don't match up.

Comment: Even if the dimensions were correct, this does not look like a SVD

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I have made a mistake in sigma matrix.

Comment: Anyway, the $V$ vectors correspond to the rows of the last matrix. It is why SVD is generally pictured as $A = U D V^T$

Comment: @Damien i have a trask with this SVD. I only want to understand a meaning of the $V_^{(o)H}$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this notation (the o)

Comment: @Damien (o) means null space

Comment: One issue is that what you show is not really a SVD, inner matrix should be quasi diagonal